# How to connect APIM to Azure Function App using Azure Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-bicep, apim

I am trying to connect Azure Function App (which have a Spring Boot application inside it) with the Azure API Management. I am able to do this using Azure UI.

But when I try this using Azure Bicep I have to manually specify all the apis that I want to show in APIM.

```js
param location string = resourceGroup().location


resource bicep_poc 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2022-09-01-preview' = {
  name: 'bicep-poc'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Consumption'
    capacity: 0
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    publisherEmail: 'abc@xyz.com'
    publisherName: 'abcd'
  }
}


// send apis
resource bicep_poc_bicep_fa_demo 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-09-01-preview' = {
  parent: bicep_poc
  name: 'bicep-fa-demo'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'bicep-fa-demo api function'
    apiRevision: '1'
    description: 'Import from "bicep-fa-demo" Function App'
    subscriptionRequired: false
    path: 'bicep-fa-demo/hello_1a'
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ]
    isCurrent: true
  }
}

resource bicep_poc_bicep_fa_demo_get_hello_world 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations@2022-09-01-preview' = {
  parent: bicep_poc_bicep_fa_demo
  name: 'get-hello-world'
  properties: {
    displayName: 'hello-world'
    method: 'GET'
    urlTemplate: '/hello-world'
    templateParameters: []
    responses: []
  }
}

resource bicep_poc_bicep_fa_demo_get_hello_world_policy 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations/policies@2022-09-01-preview' = {
  parent: bicep_poc_bicep_fa_demo_get_hello_world
  name: 'policy'
  properties: {
    value: '<policies>\r\n  <inbound>\r\n    <base />\r\n    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="bicep-fa-demo" />\r\n  </inbound>\r\n  <backend>\r\n    <base />\r\n  </backend>\r\n  <outbound>\r\n    <base />\r\n  </outbound>\r\n  <on-error>\r\n    <base />\r\n  </on-error>\r\n</policies>'
    format: 'xml'
  }
}
```

Here I need to manually add `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/operations`.

Is there any direct way to do so like UI does just by connecting lambda it creates all the apis for Http Triggers and connect it to backend (which is function app here)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way unless you're passing a swagger schema, but you can make simple GET operations easier by decomposing to a module like [this](https://github.com/Gordonby/AzureBicepServerlessAppStack/blob/main/bicep/foundation/apim-api.bicep). Inside the module I'm declaring the API, operation, policy and web tests.

The repo my linked bicep is from, shows a full end to end Azure Functions + APIM implementation... Which might be of use to you.